# How to get an order position of column values for several groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Could you help me to find an answer on one question. I have a dataframe, which contains user's id and action numbers. These numbers are not in strict order, some values are missed. Something like this:

```
print(df)

    id  action
0   2039    12
1   2039    24
2   2039    6
3   2039    42
4   2031    11
5   2031    7
6   2031    22
7   2031    23
8   2032    3
9   2032    4
10  2032    6
11  3032    77
```

And I need to get an order postiton for every user, one by one. Like this:

```
      id    action  order_posotion
0   2039    12  2
1   2039    24  3
2   2039    6   1
3   2039    42  4
4   2031    11  2
5   2031    7   1
6   2031    22  3
7   2031    23  4
8   2032    3   1
9   2032    4   2
10  2032    6   3
11  3032    77  4
```

How can I do that? 
Will be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html):

```
df['order position']=df.groupby('id').action.rank()
```

or

```
df['order position']=df.sort_values('action').groupby('id').id.cumcount()+1
```

**Output df**

```
      id  action  order position
0   2039      12               2
1   2039      24               3
2   2039       6               1
3   2039      42               4
4   2031      11               2
5   2031       7               1
6   2031      22               3
7   2031      23               4
8   2032       3               1
9   2032       4               2
10  2032       6               3
11  3032      77               1
```